# Is it safe to use cognitoIdentityId as a public userId?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

Is it safe to expose and use $ctx.identity.cognitoIdentityId as a user's public Id? Exposing cognitoIdentityId feels leaky because of the region information.

I am using AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) as my Authorization type.

I am not sure if this is relevant but my identity pool does allow for unauthenticated identities.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Cognito identity id is guaranteed to be unique in the region in which it exists, however there is one case in which it could change: identity merges.

Say you have signed in to Facebook to use your app on your phone, but use a Cognito User Pool on your tablet. If you were to want to link those accounts at some point, you would need to sign in with both login tokens once, after that providing a either token would suffice. During this single login, though, an identity merge would be kicked off. The result of this merge would be one disabled identity id, and one active id that owns both tokens. Cognito treats this process entirely randomly - it could be either that is disabled.

It's altogether possible that does not apply to your app, but if you have multiple configured providers, it's something to consider. You'd have to intercept these kinds of events and update your data store accordingly.

As far as leaking the id itself, that's a fair concern. In addition to it just looking funny with the region prefix that a non-AWS developer wouldn't understand, it could have some security risks (depending on permissions you have linked to that type of user). I might recommend some hash or encoding to obfuscate it a bit.

Comment: Interesting point, I will have to keep that in mind. 

I would like to use $ctx.identity.cognitoIdentityId to authenticate queries in the request resolver, I don't see any way of hashing it in VTL.


Would it be safe to have a query like getUserByCognitoId(String: ID): User
As long as the target application does not print out the cognitoIdentityId to the user?

Comment: Just to clarify - were you saying you'd literally expose it to an end user, or just internally use it to identify them? If the latter, you're probably okay avoiding it. I may have just misinterpreted your question a bit.

Comment: Right so I see that exposing it directly to an end user is bad. For example, displaying all cognitoIds of all a user's friends on the screen. But how about storing all of the cognitoIds of a user's friends in memory on my android app? Is there some way of extracting those cognitoIds, either by listening to the network sending them or by reading the memory of the application with some external tool?

Comment: Keeping it internal should be fine, I would think. The only real risk is if you have lots of permissions on unauthenticated users, which doesn't sound like your problem.

There isn't a good, safe way of listening for the id, but I think there's a simple way of keeping track of it: just storing it against a friend. So when you (presumably) call ListFriends, part of the response payload would include what you need. This would also expose an easy way to update it on hypothetical identity merge.